# Factoring an Identity

Tags: combinatorics

What is the factorization of $a^k - b^k$, where $0 < k < 1$ ?
Precisely, $a^k -b^k = (a-b) R$, so what is $ R$ ?

Is there any "good" Handbook that deals with such identities?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by factoring, given that $k$ is an arbitrary real number? (in $(0,1)$).

Comment: You can attempt [synthetic division](http://www.purplemath.com/modules/synthdiv.htm), but I doubt it would converge to a nice expression unless $k$ were an integer.

Comment: @Axoren: if $k$ is not a positive integer, does it make sense to talk about synthetic division?

Comment: @AhmedHussein, It boils down to the choice in coefficients of $(a - b)$ which are not necessarily integers. For example, the first step would be: $(a^k - b^k)/(a - b) = a^{k-1} + (a^{k-1}b - b^k)/(a - b)$.

Comment: @AhmedHussein However, I'm willing to cede this process does not work for arbitrary $k$, but the second $k$ is known, the procedure can be followed until we have a nicer expression.